# Obtaining mean intercept and slopes from geom_abline() using summary methods

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to overlay parameter estimates of group intercept and slope from a Bayesian analysis onto a grouped ggplot scatter-plot of actual data. I can overlay the individual lines just fine but I would really like to get a single mean line for each of the groups as well.

Here is some toy data. Three groups with differing intercepts and slopes

```
# data 
x <- rnorm(120, 0, 1)
y <- c(20 + 3*x[1:40] + rnorm(40,0.01), rnorm(40,0.01), 10 + -3*x[81:120] + rnorm(40,0.01))
group = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 40))

df <- data.frame(group,x,y)

# fake parameter estimates of intercept and slope
parsDF <- data.frame(int = c(rnorm(10,20,.5), rnorm(10,0,.5), rnorm(10,10,.5)),
                     slope = c(rnorm(10,3,.3), rnorm(10,0,.3), rnorm(10,-3,.3)),
                     group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 10))
```

Now for the plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, colour = group)) +
       geom_abline(data = parsDF, aes(intercept = int, slope = slope), colour = "gray75") + 
       geom_point() +
       facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

I thought maybe I could add a *single* mean intercept and slope line for each group via `stat.summary`-type methods, like so

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, colour = group)) +
       geom_abline(data = parsDF, aes(intercept = int, slope = slope), colour = "gray75") + 
       geom_abline(data = parsDF, aes(intercept = int, slope = slope), stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", colour = "black", linetype = "dotted") + 
       geom_point() +
       facet_wrap(~group)
```

But it just ignores those arguments and re-plots the individual lines over the existing ones.

[image]

I realise I could just calculate the mean of the intercepts and slopes for each group and brute-force that into the graph somehow but I can't see how to do that without mucking up the faceting by `group`, other than by creating another dataframe for mean slopes and intercepts and passing that into the plot as well. And I don't want to simply use `geom_smooth()` because that will use the actual data not my parameter estimates.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Doesn't look like `geom_abline` takes a stat argument, but you could probably do it the other way with `+ stat_summary(..., geom = "abline")`

Comment: Thanks @Gregor but `ggplot(df, aes(x,y, colour = group)) +
       geom_abline(data = parsDF, aes(intercept = int, slope = slope), colour = "gray75") + 
       stat_summary(data = parsDF, aes(intercept = int, slope = slope), geom = "abline", fun.y = "mean", colour = "black", linetype = "dotted") + 
       geom_point() +
       facet_wrap(~group)` returned an error message `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (30): intercept, slope, x, y`

Comment: Yeah, I guess `stat_summary` is pretty focused on `y` aesthetics, and you need `int` and `slop`. Guess you'll just have to summarize your data into a separate data frame.

Comment: Oh well never mind, not a huge bother.

Comment: whats about `library(tidyverse);   geom_abline(data = parsDF %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise_at(vars(int, slope), mean), aes(intercept = int, slope = slope, color=group), show.legend = F )`